# How to click element with zero height with Capybara?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, rspec, capybara

The error I'm getting is: `element not interactable: element has zero size`

I have an element with a button tag with text. However, the `element.style` has two attributes of `0px` `height` (and `0px` `padding`, if that matters).

The only workaround I've found is to interact with some other element that I can find (higher up in the hierarchy of the markup), and then use `x` and `y` offsets to click this button. However that ends up flaky because the size of the element can change, and the button is off to the lower right corner.

I'm willing to go the extra mile and calculate the proper coordinates, but I'm not able to figure out how to get the width of the element either. I'm also willing to just use some javascript to click as a last resort. Ideally I'd love to know if there is something more clean and elegant for this problem.

Thank you!

Comment: If the element is zero size then a user wouldn’t be able to click it either. Which element does the user actually click on? Is it a case of the UI just collapsing because the window size is too small?

Comment: @ThomasWalpole I'm not familiar with how or why it is able to produce a clickable element. I shared an album here with details: https://imgur.com/a/qCBPn84

I included what it looks like, the markup surrounding this element, and some of the properties on the button tag.

Comment: Does the style of the button change when hovered over? Is this available on a public site I can inspect?  Have you tried just clicking on any of the wrapping elements?

Comment: The style does not change on hover. It is not available publicly (but I will see if I can swing that somehow). I am able to click one of the wrapping elements and provide an x: and y: offset to get the click on the button to succeed.

Comment: @ThomasWalpole I ended up using actionbuilder in the selenium-webdriver gem that allowed me to click the button even though it is 0 height. I'm not sure why that seems to work versus the Capybara finder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using actionbuilder to work around this problem, like this:

```
el = find('button', :text => '+ 1').native
actionbuilder = page.driver.browser.action # Use actionbuilder to workaround zero height button
actionbuilder.click(el).perform
```

I'm not sure if this is the way to go but that seems to have helped and maybe might help someone else out there.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can enable js for this test and use a trick for it.

Smth like that:

```
page.execute_script("$('#container img').css('height', '10px;')")
find('#container img').click
page.execute_script("$('#container img').css('height', '0')")
```